How Does the ELM Method Approximate Solutions to Linear ODEs Without Direct Training Data?

How Does the ELM Method Approximate Solutions to Linear ODEs Without Direct Training Data?
Summary of the Problem

    I am working on solving a linear inhomogeneous ordinary differential equation (ODE) using the Extreme Learning Machine (ELM) method. The differential equation is:


$ x^2 y''(x) - 2x y'(x) + 2y(x) = 6x^4 $


    I am trying to understand how the ELM method can approximate the solution effectively without using a traditional training set of $ y(x_i) $ values.

Details and Research

    In the ELM method, the activation function used is the sigmoid function, defined as:


$ \phi_{ij} = \phi(x_i \cdot u_j + w_j) \quad \text{where } u_j \text{ and } w_j \text{ are weights and biases} $


    The matrix $ L $ is constructed as follows:


$ L_{ij} = x_i^2 u_j^2 \phi''(x_i \cdot u_j + w_j) - 2 x_i^2 u_j \phi'(x_i \cdot u_j + w_j) + 2 \phi(x_i \cdot u_j + w_j) $


    Sample points are $(x_i, 6x_i^4)$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, m$.


    The matrix equation is solved using the Moore-Penrose inverse:


$ H \cdot V = \beta $


$
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & L_{12} & \cdots & L_{1N} \\
L_{21} & L_{22} & \cdots & L_{2N} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
L_{m1} & L_{m2} & \cdots & L_{mN} \\
\phi(1) & \phi(1) & \cdots & \phi(1) \\
u_1 \phi'(1) & u_2 \phi'(1) & \cdots & u_N \phi'(1)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\vdots \\
v_N
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
6x_1^4 \\
6x_2^4 \\
\vdots \\
6x_m^4 \\
1 \\
2.9
\end{bmatrix}
$


    The last two rows in the matrix equation represent the initial conditions.


    The solution is given by:


$ V = \text{pinv}(H) \cdot \beta $


    The approximated solution is constructed as:


$ \hat{y}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} v_i \phi(u_i x + w_i) $


    This is compared with the actual solution:


$ y(x) = \frac{3}{10} x + \frac{4}{10} x^2 + \frac{3}{10} x^6 $

What I've Tried

    I have implemented the ELM method as described, using the Moore-Penrose inverse to solve for the coefficients $ V $. However, I am struggling to understand the underlying mechanism that allows the ELM method to approximate the solution accurately without directly using $ y(x_i) $ values.

Question

How does the ELM method achieve a reasonable approximation of the solution without directly using $ y(x_i) $ values as part of the training set?
What exactly is the model fitting to in this context, and how does it ensure the accuracy of the approximation?


    Any insights or explanations on the application of the ELM method in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

